# Small coolant leak in after replacing the intake gasket

Tags: chevrolet, coolant-leak, s10, intake-manifold

I have a Chevrolet s10 with a 4.3l v6 which just hit 200000 km . I got my mechanic to replace the intake manifold gasket two months ago after a huge coolant leak. It ran fine since then, however lately I noticed this little puddle of coolant building up from time to time. It is not every time I drive the truck, it shows up at random times. The puddle is pretty insignificant. I just want to make sure if it is something I should be concerned about?. My coolant level in the coolant tank is above the full mark. I also replaced the upper radiator hose 3 weeks ago. [image]

UPDATE:

Over the last two days , i tried to recreate scenario when the leak seems to happen. 
I noticed that the leak only happens when i start the vehicle in the morning or after the engine's cooled off completely. The leak seems to happen **from the bottom of the upper hose.** 
Does this mean i need to change the thermostat and the connector to the hose?

There is absolutely no leak when i drive the truck. There is no loss of power either. 
Truck doesn't seem to overheat and there is more than enough coolant in the reserve tank.

I've driven with the AC and the heater on full blast. Other than the expected power loss from the AC, i don't feel any drastic change in the pulling capability.

Comment: Yes it is. Edited the original question

Comment: The thermostat housing is right there ... if not leaking from there, there are two coolant ports (one on each head) up front where the intake manifold connects to it (coolant should pass through an area up front in the intake manifold). It could be leaking from there as well. If this was a serious leak, you'd be overheating all the time, but it appears it must just be seeping or something. Great fun! :o)

Comment: Over the last two days , i tried to recreate scenario when the leak seems to happen. I noticed that the leak only happens when i start the vehicle in the morning or after the engine's cooled off completely. The leak seems to happen from the bottom of the upper hose. Does this mean i need to change the thermostat and the connector to the hose? There is absolutely no leak when i drive the truck. There is no loss of power either. Truck doesn't seem to overheat and there is more than enough coolant in the reserve tank.

Comment: If you are saying the leak seems to happen where the radiator hose meets the neck, it may just take an adjustment of the hose itself. Ensure the hose clamp is in place proper (not below the edge of the hose and not above the top most nipple area of the neck). Then also ensure the hose clamp is tight enough.

Comment: one thing you can count on, it *will* get worse.

Answer (score 0):

Water may have weeped up threads on front manifold bolts. Your mechanic may have forgot to wrap the threads, some bolts come in contact with the antifreeze and it can seep out of the top of the bolt. Ask your mechanic if he wrapped them good.

Comment: are you  sure about this?

Answer (score 0):

try just tightening the nearby hose clamps first.  If it still seeps it may be the thermostat housing.  It could just be a gasket.  We usually put a thin bead of clear silicone on this one.  Not too much or it could squirt internally and impede the functionality of the thermostat.